# How to make a method which accept parameter or property like One in Annotaion Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex, methods, properties, attributes

what is such method in the picture bellow and how can I make such one?

I searched internet a lot and did not find any thing. tried many thing like attribute method or property method bu nothing founded.

In-fact my problem is that I want to make a method to work like this and the input parameters be optional.

[My Questions Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ive4V.png)
this is my code bellow (Except panel others are enum type) :

```
public static void Reset(System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel, formulaType formulaType, ShalvarType shalvarType = 0
            , DamanType damanType = 0, YaqeType yaqeType = 0, BalataneType balataneType = 0, AstinType astinType = 0)
        {


            object[,] collcetion = null;
            switch (formulaType)
            {
                case formulaType.Shalvar:
                    collcetion = shalvarFurmula(shalvarType);
                    break;
                case formulaType.Daman:
                    collcetion = damanFurmula(damanType);
                    break;
                case formulaType.Yaqe:
                    collcetion = yaqeFurmula(yaqeType);
                    break;
                case formulaType.Balatane:
                    collcetion = balataneFurmula(balataneType);
                    break;
                case formulaType.Astin:
                    collcetion = astinFurmula(astinType);
                    break;

            }

            //System.Windows.Forms.TextBox

            for (int i = 0; i < collcetion.Length; i++)
            {
                if (panel.Controls[collcetion[i, 0].ToString()].GetType().ToString() == "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox")
                {
                    panel.Controls[collcetion[i, 0].ToString()].Text = collcetion[i, 1].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown num = panel.Controls[collcetion[i, 0].ToString()] as System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown;
                    num.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(collcetion[i, 1]);
                }
            }

        }
```

I want to have panel and formula type but from the third one to end be like that. in fact I give the enum type the way like picture.

By the way the code i send is not complete yet.

Thankx

Comment: just make it a standard property of your attribute.

Comment: I didn't get that . let me edit the qestion to be more clear

Comment: Well as I said I didn't know even what is it . so how you want that I writh some thing for you???

At first I must show you a pic that professionals like you Understand and indentefy the type , then the whole question. but I accept that I should writhe the code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your image refers to are an `Attribute`'s optional properties, they are defined as:

```
public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string SomeData { get; set; }
}
```

What you want is to use optional parameters. You achieve this like this:

```
public void DoSomething(string data = "", int age = 0) // data will be empty if no value is given
{
}
```

And you can then call this method with both:

```
DoSomething();
DoSomething("some data");
DoSomething(age: 10);
```

Comment: I know optional parameter. but the bad point of optional parameter is that it must be give in order, for example refer to my code I just want to give AstinType  to the method  , and AstinType  is in the end. i must give other 4 parameter null or zero or ...  then at the end give the AstinType , but I want to give this directly after the second input not in the Qeue, while the way which picture use you are not concern of order of input and ...

Comment: @Heydar That's not true, look at my update. You use `parameterName: value` to specify order